# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.0.3300.0

Tags: c#

Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.0.3300.0

Comment: you need to clear the cache on the server by restarting the app pool. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: did you install the merge modules on the serve?

Comment: I mean did you install the runtime for Crystal.

Comment: see this SAP post . http://scn.sap.com/thread/1859888

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config contains crystal report reference from previous crystal report..Comment/Remove that reference in web.config. It should be inside

```xml
<system.web>
  <assemblies>
  </assemblies>
</system.web>
```

Comment: HI, I can use `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0` works well in web server, but `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0` reports the smilar error. But I can use `13.0.2000.0` in my local project. What's the problem?

Comment: Which version of crystal report installed in server please check. May be your local machine have `Version=13.0.2000.0`  installed and your server have `Version=10.2.3600.0`. Install same version in the web server.

Comment: I have no rigth to see the sever Crystal version. But I have another project use the same assemblies reference in the same server, and it works well. Strange.